# Using attributes vs complex type in saving localized strings

Tags: xml, xsd, localization

I would like to save localized strings in my xml files in such way that every text field should have a localized variants for all supported languages. Sometimes the localizations can be missing and there will always be english localization. I came up with these 2 solutions on how to do this.

a)

```
<title lang="en">iOS App Developer</title>
<title lang="sk">Vývojár aplikácií pre systém iOS</title>
```

b)

```
<title>
    <en>iOS App Developer</en>
    <sk>Vývojár aplikácií pre systém iOS</sk>
</title>
```

What are pro's and con's of these 2 solutions?

Also I'll need to write an XSD schema for this XML file, and I would like to be able to list all available localizations in one enum and then limit localized string for each field to be unique (such as there won't be 2 english localizations for one field) and also at most one for each localization.

Here is how the language enum in my XSD looks right now:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="language-type">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="en"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="sk"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```